# Would Merfolk Evolution Trade Noses for Gills?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution, merfolk

The primary purpose of the human nose is to detect scents. This is an obvious statement, as is that the primary function of the mouth is to eat. The secondary purpose of both of these features is to breath. Now Merfolk who evolve underwater would have no need for the sense of smell (as it would be replaced with taste), so would the evolution of the Merperson favor the replacement of the nose for gills?

Comment: the lungs are replaced (unless these merfolk are akin to lungfish), not the nose. also, have you ever seen a fish without nostrils?

Comment: a mammal can't become a fish this fast .A better system is starting to breath through  the skin.

Comment: Fishes have noses too, of more varied kinds than other vertebrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It wouldn't be favored. It would be required.

An organism with lungs and a nose cannot live underwater any more than you can. Before that point they **have** to evolve gills (including the "lungs"), at least in addition to land-based breathing.

**edit**: I think there was a misunderstanding. I am not claiming that any organism living in water needs gills (dolphins and other animals don't have them). Rather I am claiming that a human could not live in water without extensive modifications. While it would be possible to adapt the human organism in such a way as to allow it to live underwater without requiring gills, gills are the easiest solution as well as the one that constrains a writer the least (as in, if they have gills they don't need to have the merfolk surface all the time and can place them in deep water environments as well).

Comment: dolphins don't have gills and can stay underwater for about 30 seconds, for them it's enough to hunt,sleep and reproduce.

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια sure, but that's a pretty heavy disadvantage for merfolk and one that would limit the author a lot in what they are trying to build. (30 seconds? are you sure? I thought it was 15 minutes or so...).

Comment: 15 minutes isn't the average for dolphins the same way 20 minutes records with pure oxygen preparation isn't the average for all humans...

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια I see. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The mammalian diving reflex is an impressive adaptation. "-- the Sperm whale who frequently makes dives to about 2000 meters, and also the Elephant seal who dives to around 1500 meters. One of the most studied marine mammals is the Weddell seal who dives to about 700 meters and can stay submerged for up to a registered 82 minutes!" At http://www.thewildclassroom.com/cetaceans/adaptations.html A bit more than 30 seconds. Google diving reflex and be amazed.

Comment: @a4android keep in mind 82 minutes is the record time. The average human can't stay underwater for almost 9 minutes either.

Comment: @Annonymus Sure that's for seals. We're not talking about average humans. This is about aquatically adapted merfolk. Reasonable to expect they will possess a strong diving reflex. Are they half-mammal & half-fish? Whatever! The gills idea doesn't feel right. Very difficult for merfolk when they're out of the water. Highly modified for the marine environment, absolutely! Mythical creatures & biology never go together well.